# I need help in restructuring a dataframe to align the dates for two variables associated with each participant ID

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am currently working on a vast medical dataset wherein several measurements (up to 6) are stored for different variables. I have made a long table as I wish to calculate the correlation between these variables. The issue that I have however, is that A, not all participants have equal amounts of measurements for each variable (some participants have 6 measurements some 1), B not all participant have equal measurements for each variable (VarA might have 3 measurements whereas varB might have 1) and C the final and biggest issue, the variables are time sensitive, therefore, only variables that have been recorded within x amount of time of one another can be considered usable.

The issue is that VarA measurement 1 might align with VarB measurement 2 or even 3. I therefore need to check for each participant, at what date the measurement was taken, calculate the opposite of the sum of the dates of these measurements and reorganise the dataset.

I want to go from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I have tried

```
# initialization 
time_period <- 0
time_list <- vector("numeric", length = nrow(dates_long))
ref_date <- dates_long$date_[1]

for (i in 1:nrow(dates_long)) {
  if (i == 1 || dates_long$Id[i] != dates_long$.Id[i - 1]) {
  
    ref_date <- as.Date(dates_long$date_[i], "%d-%m-%Y")
    time_period <- 0
  }
  
  date <- as.Date(dates_long$date_[i], "%d-%m-%Y")
 
  # Check for missing values in date
  if (!is.na(date)) {
    if (as.numeric(date - ref_date, units = "days") <= 45) {
      time_list[i] <- time_period
    } else {
      time_period <- time_period + 1 
      time_list[i] <- time_period
      ref_date <- date
    }
  } else {
    # Handle missing date values, for example, set time_list[i] to a specific value
    time_list[i] <- NA
  }
}

dates_long$time_list <- time_list
```

With this code I tried to assign each matching pair for each ID to a time_list. The first match would be time 1 the second time 2 etc. I was hoping that after I could rearange according to this column.

However, sadly this is not working. I hope any of you smart people might know the answer.

Kind regards

Edit: dput of sample dataframe:

```
dates_long <- structure(list(Participant.ld = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), varA_date = structure(c(16576, 
16942, 17308, 17674, 18040, 18407, 16160, 16912, 17308, NA, NA, 
NA, 16576, 16942, 17308, 17674, 18040, 18407), class = "Date"), 
    varA_value = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 11L, 22L, 33L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 44L, NA, NA, NA, NA), varB_date = structure(c(16942, 
    17674, 18040, NA, NA, NA, 16942, 17308, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16952, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), varB_value = c(100L, 
    200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 111L, 222L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    555L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

```
    dataset <- structure(
  list(
    Participant.Id = 1:5,
    
    var_dep_date_1 = as.Date(c("15-06-2013", "02-03-2013", "20-10-2012", "07-08-2015", "03-09-2014"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
    var_dep_date_2 = as.Date(c("15-06-2014", "02-03-2014", "20-10-2013", "07-08-2016", "05-06-2017"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
    var_dep_date_3 = as.Date(c("15-06-2017", "21-06-2015", NA, "17-03-2017", NA), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
    var_dep_date_4 = as.Date(c("15-06-2018", "02-03-2016", NA, "07-08-2018", NA), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
    var_dep_date_5 = as.Date(c(NA, "02-03-2019", NA, "07-08-2021", NA), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
    var_dep_date_6 = as.Date(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
    
    dep_var_value_1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L),
    dep_var_value_2 = c(15L, 25L, 35L, 45L, 55L),
    dep_var_value_3 = c(20L, 25L, NA, 45L, NA),
    dep_var_value_4 = c(25L, 30L, NA, 50L, NA),
    dep_var_value_5 = c(NA, 35L, NA, 55L, NA),
    dep_var_value_6 = c(NA, 35L, NA, NA, NA),
    
    var_indep_date_1 = as.Date(c("25-06-2011", "10-03-2013", "20-10-2013", "07-08-2014", "15-09-2014"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
    var_indep_date_2 = as.Date(c("16-06-2013", "21-03-2014", "05-03-2017", "07-08-2015", "03-06-2017"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
    var_indep_date_3 = as.Date(c("16-06-2014", "10-06-2015", NA, "30-07-2016", "10-08-2018"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
    var_indep_date_4 = as.Date(c("15-06-2018", "05-04-2016", NA, "07-08-2018", NA), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
    var_indep_date_5 = as.Date(c(NA, "02-03-2019", NA, NA, NA), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
    var_indep_date_6 = as.Date(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
    
    varA_indep_value_1 = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L),
    varA_indep_value_2 = c(110L, 210L, 310L, 410L, 510L),
    varA_indep_value_3 = c(120L, 220L, NA, 420L, 520L),
    varA_indep_value_4 = c(130L, 230L, NA, 430L, NA),
    varA_indep_value_5 = c(NA, 240L, NA, NA, NA),
    varA_indep_value_6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
     
    varB_indep_value_1 = c(101L, 201L, 301L, 401L, 501L),
    varB_indep_value_2 = c(111L, 211L, 311L, 411L, 511L),
    varB_indep_value_3 = c(121L, 221L, NA, 421L, 521L),
    varB_indep_value_4 = c(131L, 231L, NA, 431L, NA),
    varB_indep_value_5 = c(NA, 241L, NA, NA, NA),
    varB_indep_value_6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),

    varC_indep_value_1 = c(102L, 202L, 302L, 402L, 502L),
    varC_indep_value_2 = c(112L, 212L, 312L, 412L, 512L),
    varC_indep_value_3 = c(122L, 222L, NA, 422L, 522L),
    varC_indep_value_4 = c(132L, 232L, NA, 432L, NA),
    varC_indep_value_5 = c(NA, 242L, NA, NA, NA),
    varC_indep_value_6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)),


  class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -5L)
)

dataset_long <- dataset %>% 
                          pivot_longer(-c(Participant.Id),
                                       names_to = c(".value", "time"),
                                       names_pattern = "(\\w+)(\\d+)")
```

There are multiple independent variables, and one dependent variable. All independent variables were measured on the same date, the dependent variable is the issue, this one can be measured on different dates. I have to match the correct dependent variable measurement date, to the correct independent variable measurement date. I only want to keep the dates in a dataset that have a matching date.

Comment: What's the tolerance for considering the dates 'matching'?  If you have two entries for varA that are within the time frame for one entry of varB, do they both use it or just the closest?

Comment: The tolerance is something we plan to play with. There shouldnt be 2 dates that are within 2 months of one another, however, to be safe I would like to first try 31 days or 1 month

Comment: Looking at that display I'm struck be the fact that none of the columns with what humans would think of as a date could possibly be objects that R would consider to be dates. So the first thing to do would be to learn how to convert character values into objects of class `"Date"`.

Comment: @IRTFM thanks for your comment. I do not understand what you mean. This was just a mock up in excel as I can't share the actual data. I used the as.Date and then '''%d-%m-%Y'. Is this not what you meant? This should turn them into object class "Date" rigth?

Comment: It might or might not. You need to post actual R code that works on an actual R object. PNGs of Excel mockups are not an acceptable method of presenting input. As an example of the ambiguity I don't see anything that corresponds to `dates_long$date_` or `dates_long$.Id`

Comment: @IRTFM I have added a `dput` of the data in the screenshot with date formats sorted.  Typically we would expect the OP to do this but I was messing with this type of conversion any way so did it as a quick exercise.

Comment: The second line throws an error.  `time_list <- vector("numeric", length = nrow(dates_long))
Error: object 'dates_long' not found` You need to understand and fix  your errors in the use of R at a more basic level before presenting a complex process. When I fix that error by assigning the structure() result to `dates_long` I get `Error in if (!is.na(date)) { : argument is of length zero`

Comment: @PGSA, although I believe you are trying to help, it is possible that the major problem with the data input may not be related to the presentation of the data as a screenshot, but rather with this mock data not properly representing the OP's dataset. I think the question would be improved if we waited for the OP to include a proper example `dput(their_data)`

Comment: That's fair.  @y.a - please feel free to delete my edit to your original post if you think it's a poor match to your existing data.

Comment: Dear all, I am very sorry for my question and the way it was asked. I was ill the past days and therefore have not responded. I have written a fake dataset that better represents my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt - not sure this is exactly what you are after but in the absence of a more complete question with reproducible data, this is my attempt:

```
library(tidyverse)

# first create a true-r long form dataset:
dates_longer <- dates_long |> pivot_longer(cols = -c(Participant.ld),
                           names_to = c("Variable", ".value"),
                           names_sep = "_")

# next, establish our tolerance:
tolerance <- days(31)

# now do the main work:
dates_longer %>% 
  group_by(Participant.ld) %>%
  arrange(date, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(datelag = date - lag(date, 1, default = date[1]-(tolerance+days(1))),
         # gives us a rolling "days since last entry"
         cluster = cumsum(datelag > tolerance | is.na(datelag))) %>%
         # starts a new cluster every time the gap is either greater than the tolerance
         # or if there's an NA date
  pivot_wider(names_from = Variable,
              names_glue = "{Variable}_{.value}", 
              values_from = c(value, date)) %>%
         # now pivoted back to the original format
  group_by(Participant.ld, cluster) %>%
  fill(starts_with("var"), .direction = "downup") %>%
  slice_head(n=1) %>%
         # cuts the set to one consolidated row for each cluster
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-c(datelag, cluster))
```

This gives:

```
# A tibble: 30 × 5
   Participant.ld varA_value varB_value varA_date  varB_date 
            <int>      <int>      <int> <date>     <date>    
 1              1         10         NA 2015-05-21 NA        
 2              1         20        100 2016-05-21 2016-05-21
 3              1         30         NA 2017-05-22 NA        
 4              1         40        200 2018-05-23 2018-05-23
 5              1         50        300 2019-05-24 2019-05-24
 6              1         60         NA 2020-05-25 NA        
 7              1         NA        400 NA         NA        
 8              1         NA        500 NA         NA        
 9              1         NA        600 NA         NA        
10              2         11         NA 2014-03-31 NA
```